# Oracle job alert notification

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am running oracle 11g. I try to setup an email notification for a job.

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_job_email_notification (
  job_name         =>  'JOB_COLLECT_SESS_DATA',
  recipients       =>  'kaushik.guha@bmo.com',
  events           =>  'job_failed'/*,
  filter_condition => ':event.error_code=600'*/);
END;
/
```

And I get:

```
PLS-00302: component 'ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION' must be declared
```

Is it some issue related to privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function exists in [11.2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23448/d_sched.htm#BABBFBGI) but not in [11.1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI).

You may be able to reproduce that functionality by creating another job that looks at job statuses:

```
select *
from dba_scheduler_job_run_details
where job_name = 'JOB_COLLECT_SESS_DATA'
    and status = 'FAILED'
    and additional_info like 'ORA-00600%'
order by log_id desc;
```

That query works at least for some errors.  But ORA-00600 errors are always special and may not always show up in that table for all I know.  You'll want to test this carefully.

Comment: Thank you. But how can i set up email alert?

Comment: @Kaushik: Create a job that runs every X minutes, add a predicate like `and (sysdate - cast(log_date as date)) * 24 * 60 <= [X]` to the above query, and email any results using UTL_MAIL.  This won't be perfect since jobs don't always run on time for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I set up a perl script which runs periodically as a cron job, which prints warnings when errors in the DBMS-jobs have occured. Because my crontab has a `MAILTO=<email@domain.com>` setting, all warnings are going to be sent to me by email.

```
my $dbh  = ... # set up a database connection using DBI
my $jobs = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT * FROM USER_JOBS", { Slice=>{}});

for my $job ( @$jobs ) {
    if ($job->{NEXT_DATE} eq '01-JAN-4000') {
        warn "DBMS-Job $job->{WHAT} is currently stopped.\n";
        warn "Last running at: $job->{LAST_DATE} $job->{LAST_SEC}\n";
    }
    elsif ( $job->{FAILURES} ) {
        warn "DBMS-Job $job->{WHAT} has failures.\n";
        warn "Last running at: $job->{LAST_DATE} $job->{LAST_SEC}\n";
    }
    else {
        warn "DBMS-Job $job->{WHAT} is broken.\n";
        warn "Last running at: $job->{LAST_DATE} $job->{LAST_SEC}\n";
    }
}
```